# Как отключить освещение сцены по умолчанию в PascalABC.NET в библиотеке Graph3D?

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Имеется такая простая программа на языке Паскаль в среде PascalABC.Net:

```
uses Graph3D;
begin
  View3D.ShowGridLines := False;
  View3D.BackgroundColor := Colors.Black;
  Cylinder(0,0,0,5,2,True, Colors.Blue);
  Rectangle3D(0,0,-0.01,30,30,OrtZ,OrtX,Colors.Green);
  Sphere(4, 4, 2, 2, Colors.Wheat);
end.
```

Этот код производит вот такую сцену:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, на ней присутствует источник. А если сцену покрутить, то окажется что не один. В целом, в одном из руководств к библиотеке Graph3D так и сказано:
*"По умолчанию сцена освещается рассеянным светом, дополненным несколькими
направленными источниками света"*

А можно ли как-то убрать источники света по умолчанию? Или с ними придётся иметь дело всё время?

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://pascalabc.net/downloads/Presentations/Tutorials/Graph3D.pdf) на слайде про освещение есть пример управления освещением. Ещё в [справке](https://pascalabc.net/downloads/pabcnethelp/index.htm?page=PABCUnits/Graph3D/Files/Graph3D%20variables.html) есть переменная Lights, возможно можно что-то сделать через неё. Но я не проверял.

Comment: Именно там я это и нашёл. Но ничего про ответ на мой вопрос:)

Comment: @Alekcvp, покопался в переменной Lights, но без результативно:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации нет описания того как удалить источники света по умолчанию, но есть исходный код (Graph3D.pas:4762) в котором мы можем увидеть куда и как этот источник света добавляется

```pascal
hvp.Children.Add(new DefaultLights);
```

Тут hvp является экзмепляром класса HelixViewport (это класс библиотеки https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit) на базе которой строится весь модуль Graph3D

Описания и реализации класса DefaultLights нет в исходниках проекта, но есть в исходниках библиотеки helix (https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/blob/master/Source/HelixToolkit.Wpf.Shared/Visual3Ds/LightSetups/DefaultLights.cs)

Т.е. что бы решить вашу проблему надо добавить "грязный" хак - удалить первый дочерний объект из hvp и добавить свой источник света

```pascal
Invoke(()->hvp.Children.RemoveAt(1));
```

Добавить свой

```pascal
Lights.AddPointLight(Colors.SkyBlue, P3D(50,10,50));
```

Можно до кучи добавить окружающий свет (раз мы его удалили и в исходниках нет методов для его создания)

```pascal
Invoke(()->LightsGroup.Children.Add(new System.Windows.Media.Media3D.AmbientLight(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(30, 30, 30))));
```

Comment: Божечки, спасибо огромное!!! за грязный хук;)

Answer (score 0):

Как заметил умный человек в комментариях, можно поискать в классе Lights подсказки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Попробовал вывести количество источников света: результат возвращает 0. Попробовал вызвать метод Lights.RemoveLights(0):
**Ошибка времени выполнения: Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток.**
Возможно можно как-то работать с потоками в этом языке, но в справочнике ничего не нашёл. Нашёл только директиву **lock**, которая блокирует объект и гарантирует, что код будет выполняться одним потоком.

А потом решил напрямую вызвать данный метод, так как внутри класса Lights идёт работа именно с объектом LightsGroup:

```
Invoke(()->LightsGroup.Children.Clear());
```

Метод успешно выполнился, также оставив сцену с фантомными источниками света:(